# Make a prop available to the HOC

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, higher-order-components

I have written a Higher Order Component that dispatches a fetch method to the API and provides `data` and (loading)`status` to the wrapped component, given an `id`

My question is: how to make the `id` property available to the HOC?

```
import React from 'react'

import withObject from '../hocs/withObject'

const Organization = ({status, object}) => {
  if (status.error) return <>error message</>
  if (status.isFetching) return <>spinner</>
  return <h1>{object.name}</h1>
}

// this works
// export default withObject(
//   Organization,
//   {element: 'organization', id: 'hard-coded-id'}
// )

// this does not, see below
export default ({id}) => withObject(
  Organization,
  {element: 'organization', id}
)
```

For full info, here is what the HOC does

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { fetchObject } from '../actions/objects'
import { fetchIfNeeded } from '../utils'

const withObject = (WrappedComponent, {element, id}) => {

  const hoc = ({status={}, object={}, fetchObject}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
      fetchIfNeeded(
        status,
        ()=>fetchObject(element, id),
      )
    })

    return <WrappedComponent {...{object, status, element, id}}/>
  }

  const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    object: state.data[element][id],
    status: state.objects[element][id]
  })

  const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchObject
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(hoc)

}

export default getObject
```

This gives me an error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, compare, WrappedComponent, displayName}).
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused - your pass the `id` in to your HOC, it's available already - is the problem that it is undefined in your useEffect?

Comment: actually, it's available in `getObject` but you don't appear to be calling `hoc` anywhere

Comment: I have never seen `useEffect` used as a callback

Comment: I think this will help you. See [Refs in HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html#forwarding-refs-in-higher-order-components).

Comment: @WillJenkins I try to make it available to the `getObject` HOC, and `getObject` would work fine if I can pass the `id` to it. Works fine with hard coded `id`.

Comment: @DennisVash Do you mean to suggest that this is an anti-pattern? I cannot see anything wrong here.

Comment: @RahulSaini, I cannot see how it does? My problem is making a prop value available to the HOC, not to forward something from HOC to wrappedComponent.